# Inserting values into previously null fields, locking them

Tags: vba

I'm working in MS Access 2013 and I want to write some VBA code for a button I made on a form. I want the code to do 2 things: insert values I designate into null fields and lock all fields in the form.

acCmdFreezeColumn doesn't seem appropriate since it doesn't refer to the form. My current thought is to use this framework:

```
Sub buttonLockForm1_Click()

Dim intResponse As Integer

intResponse = MsgBox( _
    Prompt:="Are you sure you want to lock the form?", _
    Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2, _
    Title:="Lock the Form?")

If intResponse = vbYes Then
 ...
 ...

Else: If intResponse = vbNo Then Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean controls on a form (like textboxes). Null and empty strings is different in VBA btw. Put this inside your if (and the Dim at the top obviously)

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    if isnull(ctl.Value) or ctl.value = "" then _
        ctl.value = "Value I want to save"
    if ctl.name <> "Name of control I don't want to lock, like buttons" then _
        ctl.enabled = false
Next ctl
```

controlname.enabled = false makes the control greyed out and locks it. You can also use controlname.visible = false to make it invisible, and controlname.locked = false to make it still white bg, but lock it disabling editing.